# Global arrayList cannot be printed in one method but can be in another

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Global variable makeBitmap ArrayList in which I inserted values in a function/method called CreateArrayList. When I call the function SaveFs, I want to be able to print out the values in the makeBitmap arraylist. For some reason, it's not printing out anything. My main class, which is not included below, calls createArrayList method first then SaveFs to make sure there will be some values in there. For some reason it is not being printed when I call SaveFs method. The makeBitmap ArrayList is empty, I don't know why I made it global already, I printed it out in createArrayList, and the values are there, Idk why is it empty in SaveFs. NOTE:  Deleted the code.

Comment: please attach the calls for these methods (createArraylist and FormatArraylist).. any chance that you create a new object each time you call a method?

Comment: There is nothing as "global" in Java. And, please write a smallest runnable code to demonstrate your problem. And, please give a sensible title

Comment: Why you dont you makeBitmap directly in your while loop ??

Comment: Add the function calls. Thanks.

Comment: Already tried it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you just write a smallest little program which involve only your way to access the array list and try to reproduce the problem? I bet after you wrote that, you can spot your own problem (for which is something not shown here, possibly a duplicated local variable)

Comment: I added a runnable version of my code. Please help. I could not figure what the arraylist is not printing out in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`FileSystems runit = new FileSystems();`

is inside your while loop, so you get a clean copy of it each time you go round. Therefore the ArrayList you populate the first time around will not be found the second time you go around.

Should work fine if you put

`FileSystems runit = new FileSystems();`

on the line above

`while(!done){`

Comment: You're welcome. If it was right, you might like to mark the answer correct, so that other people coming to look at the question can see the solution. Thanks!